# How can I add Event Listener to a function expression

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In my html code, i have a button

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

and a javascript code:

```
var trial;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", tro)

function tro() { 
    if (trial == undefined) {
        alert("Good Programming") 
    }
    else {
        alert("Bad Programming")   
    }
};
```

If the button is clicked, it returns "good programming". However, with an onclick attribute on my button, I can control the function even in it's anonymous state and get the same result

```
<button id="btn" onclick="tro()">
```

Javascript code:

```
var trial;

var x = function() { 
    if (trial == undefined) {
        alert("Good Programming") 
    }
    else {
        alert("Bad Programming") 
    }
};
```

but using the addEventListener (without the onclick attribute) for a function expression will do nothing:

```
var trial;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", tro)

var x = function() { 
    if (trial == undefined) {
        alert("Good Programming") 
    }
    else {
        alert("Bad Programming") 
    }
};
```

How can I add an event handler to a function expression that will successfully execute the code.

Comment: For the function expression, the name *tro* is only available within the function itself (except for buggy old versions of IE), so `addEventListener("click", tro)` does nothing useful. Also, that call is before the function is created, so even if you change it to `addEventListener("click", x)`, at that point the value of *x* is undefined.

Comment: @UchennaAjah I think the last chunk of your code after the editing is wrong, there's no declaration of the identifier `tro` anywhere. In that case, it would be undefined and you will be passing `undefined` as event listener.

Answer (score 1):

At that point `tro` function isn't defined. Try to declare it before the `addEventListener` call and use the `x` variable:

```
var trial;

var x = function tro() { 

  if (trial == undefined) {
    alert("Good Programming") 
  } else { 
    alert("Bad Programming") 
  }

}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", x);
```

Why do you have to use the `x` variable? Because giving a name to a function when you are assigning it isn't equivalent to have a reference to the function object. You are just giving a name to it, but you don't have a reference to it. The reference will be the `x` variable.

Here you have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PeZbyd?editors=1010).

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. There was an error in the example i gave. var x is not meant to have tro. var x = function() { code... }. Let me correct that now so that I don't get the wrong answers

Answer (score 0):

**Anonymous function**

```js
var trial;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() { 
  alert(trial == undefined ? "Bad Programming" : "Good Programming");
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

**tro function** (has to be declared before being called)

```js
function tro() { 
  alert(trial == undefined ? "Bad Programming" : "Good Programming");
}

var trial;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", tro);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: You're right, fixed it and I'll try to give more detailed answers in the future. Thanks!